# PHP file_get_contents() from another file file_get_contents()

Tags: php, file-get-contents

How can i get content from a file with file_get_contents() that includes the function file_get_contents() to get content from another file?

for axample:

a.php -> file_get_contents(b.php)

b.php -> file_get_contents(www.google.com)

i want to have html output from www.google.com in a.php

EDIT: a.php is on a different server than b.php

Comment: Wouldn't `include "b.php"` to execute b.php be better than `file_get_contents(b.php)`?

Comment: its on another server :S

Comment: Reading from a file with `file_get_contents` only gets you the content of that file, it will not be parsed as PHP. If B is reachable via HTTP, you could use the HTTP URL with `file_get_contents`, _then_ the file will be parsed. However, this seems a little convoluted – what’s the reason you can’t just request the target URL in A directly?

Comment: because for receiing the content from the unknown page ;) i hae an ip restriction of about 500/day.. i want to change the ip

Comment: If `b.php` is on a different server, then you have to use `file_get_contents('http://different.server.name.com/b.php');`, not simply `file_get_contents('b.php')`

Comment: Do you have permission to change b.php?

Comment: what do you mean "to change" i have ftp access

Comment: So you have 2 servers, in one server you have your a.php, second you have b.php, and you are taking content of google.php with file_get_contents() in b.php, what you want is take the google.com content into a.php by using b.php, if its true check my answer again.

Comment: a.php is on server a, b.php is on server b and the page i want to scrape is on the web

Answer (score 0):

a.php (in first server)

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("http://mysecondserver.com/b.php");

?>
```

b.php (in second server)

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("http://www.google.com");

?>
```

When you open a.php, it is going to take the html content of b.php, and b.php is taking the html content of google.com, so i guess you are done.

Comment: b.php is on a different server

Comment: Manuel Z, ok then, what about writing it in the question? It's cleaver right?

Comment: you mean your server can't access `http://mysecondserver.com/b.php` i'm really curious about what your project is.

Answer (score -2):

The same way you get content from another file that doesn`t have file_get_contents, you can use file_get_contents() as many times as u want in as many files as you want.

For ex:

1.php

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("2.php");

?>
```

2.php

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("3.php");

?>
```

3.php

```
<?php

echo "OK";

?>
```

The output will be - OK

Comment: but it wont work. i have in both files just that function but result in a.php is null. i get the json result but the field for the html markup is null

Comment: Will the output be "OK"? I think not!

Comment: If it's on the same server, that won't work. `2.php` will echo the PHP code in `3.php`. If 2 and 2 are on different servers, it will work.

Comment: I`m 100% positive that i u will open 1.php, the output will be - OK

Comment: @EdvinasJ: The PHP code in the file will not be parsed/executed, when you open it with `file_get_contents` over the file system. When you use HTTP to access it, then it will be executed.

Comment: no it is not.. i put the results in a json array and the field where the html code should be is always null. not empty, its null

Comment: btw, a.php is on a different server than b.php

Comment: @CBroe, just tested in on my local - seems to work fine, PHP code executed in every file, works fine with HTTP as well, maybe it depends on PHP configurations.

Comment: @EdvinasJ - Then you have a unique version of PHP, with a unique version of the `file_get_contents()` function; because there is no way the code should echo "OK" if you execute 1.php, it should echo `<?php

echo file_get_contents("3.php");

?>`